# After upgrading to WebStorm 2018.1, I am getting a "Protected member is not accessible" in react native for this.setState

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, webstorm, eslint

From the WebStorm settings for ESLint I have:

```
Node Interpreter: 9.5.0
ESLint Package: 4.19.1
WebStorm: 2018.1
```

This warning did not show up before, but now if I have something as simple as:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hello: 'world' };
    this.updateSomeState = this.updateSomeState.bind(this);
  }

  updateSomeState(newString) {
    this.setState({ hello: newString });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SomeMagicButton onPress={newString => this.updateSomeState(newString)} /> 
    );
  }
}
```

the `this.setState(` is underlined with "Protected member is not accessible". This is occurring across all of my files, but functionality is still fine, and it is indeed accessible.

Here's a screenshot to see it in action (excuse the needless empty line):

[image]

Any ideas on what I can do to get rid of this?

Comment: I'm having this issue too. I've not found a way to get rid of it yet. Hopefully it'll get fixed in the next update.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is tracked as [WEB-32186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32186), please follow it for updates